# How to dynamically bind multiple json values in a single spinner?

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I have a json array which has bullet1 and bullet 2 values to be binded in a single spinner.

[{"id":7,"description":"Height dusting","is_active":true,"createdBy":1,"CreatedOn":"2018-02-20T19:48:16","ModifiedBy":null,"ModifiedOn":null,"Bullet1":"Done","Bullet2":"Not Done"},

{"id":8,"description":"Cobwebs removed","is_active":true,"createdBy":1,"CreatedOn":"2018-02-20T19:48:17","ModifiedBy":null,"ModifiedOn":null,"Bullet1":"Yes","Bullet2":"No"},

{"id":9,"description":"Side walls cleaned","is_active":true,"createdBy":1,"CreatedOn":"2018-02-20T19:48:17","ModifiedBy":null,"ModifiedOn":null,"Bullet1":"Yes","Bullet2":"No"}],"token":null,"ActionName":"GetQuestionnairesByLocation"}]

So now dynamically there are 3 spinners and according to that only 2 values should be seen in respective spinners.
First Spinner - Done, Not Done.
Second Spinner - Yes, No.
Third Spinner - Yes, No.
But the problem i am facing is every spinner is getting binded with 6 values.(Done, Not Done, Yes, No, Yes, No)

Code :

```
ArrayList<UserFormModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ResponseArray");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = 
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        UserFormModel userFormModel = new 
                        UserFormModel();
                        userFormModel.setId(jsonObject1.getInt("id"));
                        userFormModel.setDescription
                        (jsonObject1.getString("description"));
                        list.add(jsonObject1.getString("Bullet1"));
                        list.add(jsonObject1.getString("Bullet2"));
                        userFormModel.setBulletsList(list);
                        arrayList.add(userFormModel);

                    }
                    UserFormsAdapter locationMasterAdapter = new 
                    UserFormsAdapter(GetQuestions.this, arrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(locationMasterAdapter);
                    locationMasterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Adapter class :

```
private ArrayList<UserFormModel> userFormModelArrayList;
Activity home;

public UserFormsAdapter(Activity home, ArrayList<UserFormModel> 
userFormModelArrayList) {
    this.home = home;
    this.userFormModelArrayList = userFormModelArrayList;
}
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
parent) {
    View grid;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        home.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_questions_row, null);
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
    final UserFormModel userFormModel = 
    userFormModelArrayList.get(position);
    TextView textDesc = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) grid.findViewById(R.id.chooseBullets);
    String desc = userFormModel.getDescription();
    textDesc.setText(desc);

    CustomDropdownAdapter customDropdownAdapter = new 
    CustomDropdownAdapter(home, userFormModel.getBulletsList());
    spinner.setAdapter(customDropdownAdapter);
    return grid;
}
```

what is it that i need to do for my above solution to run??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is beacuase you are initialize your List outside of for loop. try to initialize your list in for loop.

```
ArrayList<UserFormModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list;\\don't initialize the list here just declare the list.
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ResponseArray");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = 
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        list = new ArrayList<>();\\try to initialize your list here.
                        UserFormModel userFormModel = new 
                        UserFormModel();
                        userFormModel.setId(jsonObject1.getInt("id"));
                        userFormModel.setDescription
                        (jsonObject1.getString("description"));
                        list.add(jsonObject1.getString("Bullet1"));
                        list.add(jsonObject1.getString("Bullet2"));
                        userFormModel.setBulletsList(list);
                        arrayList.add(userFormModel);

                    }
                    UserFormsAdapter locationMasterAdapter = new 
                    UserFormsAdapter(GetQuestions.this, arrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(locationMasterAdapter);
                    locationMasterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: great thanks it worked. May i know why do i have to initialize it inside the for loop ?